# EL to get the first element in ArrayList

Tags: jsf, el

I'm using JSF 1.1. I've read some posts about this and those posts seem to suggest that I should be able to use the `[]` notation to get the element in ArrayList. But I keep getting this error

> javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException - Bean: com.arch.myaccount.jsf.DeviceReferenceFieldMaskJTO, property: 0

At a lost at moment.  Hope someone can give me some pointers.

Below is the JSP code.  devRefs is a `ArrayList<ArrayList<DeviceReferenceFieldMaskJTO>>`, which means that devRef is `ArrayList<DeviceReferenceFieldMaskJTO>`.  The error occurred on the line where I try to do `<h:outputText value="#{devRef[0].maskTypeDesc }" />`.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{devRefs}" var="devRef" rendered="#{not empty devRefs }" columnClasses="deviceReferenceLabelColumn, deviceReferenceValueColumn">
    <h:column> 
        <h:outputText value="#{devRef[0].maskTypeDesc }" /> <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURRING -->
    </h:column> 
    <h:column>
        <h:dataTable border="1" cellspacing="0" value="#{devRef}" var="mask">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{mask.fieldLabel }" />
            </h:column> 
            <h:column>
                <h:panelGrid>
                    <h:inputText value="#{mask.fieldValue }" /> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{mask.instruction}" rendered="#{mask.hasInstruction}" style="color:#C00000;font-weight:bold;font-size:0.9em;top:-4px;"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:column> 
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>                                 
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: The error tells that `#{devRef}` is a `com.arch.myaccount.jsf.DeviceReferenceFieldMaskJTO`, not a `java.util.ArrayList`. How's that unclear? You're apparently just not running the code you think you're running.

Comment: shouldnt the value be BeanName.propertyName ?

Comment: This is where it gets confusing to me.  #{devRef} should be a `ArrayList<DeviceReferenceFieldMaskJTO>`. Notice that the 2nd column is a datatable that uses devRef as value ==> `<h:dataTable border="1" cellspacing="0" value="#{devRef}" var="mask">`.  If I comment out the line in error (`<h:outputText value="#{devRef[0].maskTypeDesc }" />`) everything works fine.  The 2nd table works would mean that devRef is an ArrayList.

Comment: Okay. Well, JSF 1.1 has so many weird bugs. To exclude it from being the cause, please first try upgrading to JSF 1.2. Any JSF 1.1 application is forwards compatible with JSF 1.2 without any changes in code (expect of places where a JSF 1.1 specific bug is incorrectly been assumed as specified behavior, of course).

Comment: ops.  Sorry, you are right Balus.  I've one too many inner table.  Strange that the 2nd inner table works.  But thank you, you've solved the problem I'm facing.